# How to check if a user is a local admin, explicitly or inherited from group, in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, admin, local

Is there an easy way to do this for any user, not just the current one?

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: Bill_Stewart is wonder if you are asking the wrong question to solve a different issue entirely.

Comment: @Matt is correct about what I am asking. Make sure that you don't really have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

The `WindowsIdentity` class has [a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td3046fc(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a UPN (UserPrincipalName):

```
$WindowsIdentity  = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity "bob@ad.org.tld"
$WindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $WindowsIdentity

$WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
```

Comment: Could you do this against a remote server?

Comment: @Starks Remotely you could use `gwmi -Class Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $Computer` or `gcim -Class Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $Computer` remotely, although it's somewhat involved to get to what you want and there's no automatic nested group resolution.